# Can we do Speech Recognition and Video Capture in Android using camerax simultaneously?

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition, android-video-record

I want to implement an app that can convert text to speech and record videos (with audio) simultaneously.
But when I am calling both function either one of them working (the recent one that has been called). Can anyone suggest some ways to implement these two together.
`

```
speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity)
        val speechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM,
        )
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,10000)
//        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,30000)
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/MP3")
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true)

        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(object : RecognitionListener {
            override fun onReadyForSpeech(bundle: Bundle?) {
                speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent)
            }
            override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {}
            override fun onRmsChanged(v: Float) {}
            override fun onBufferReceived(bytes: ByteArray?) {}
            override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
                // changing the color of our mic icon to
                // gray to indicate it is not listening
                // #FF6D6A6A
            }

            override fun onError(i: Int) {}

            override fun onResults(bundle: Bundle) {
            }

            override fun onPartialResults(bundle: Bundle) {
                val result = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)

                if (result != null) {
                    for (i in 0 until result.size){
                        text.add(result[0])
                        Log.d("Record",result[0])
                        //binding.tvtext.text = binding.tvtext.text.toString() + result[0]
                    }

                }
            }
            override fun onEvent(i: Int, bundle: Bundle?) {}

        })
        speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent)
    }
```

`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hello, did you find any solution for this problem? i need to implement same functionality in my app too. the problem here is that, both camera and speech recognizer wants to use android system's microphone, where it is not possible. only one of them can use microphone.

Comment: ya i was also facing the same issue. Till now didn't got any solution